# Padding in SSRS 2005

Tags: reporting-services, padding

In my report I am using the following expression that displays the days of the week from a multi select parameter and concatenating it with a single select parameter that shows the time.

```
Join(Parameters!DelDay.Label, space(2) + Parameters!time.Label + vbcrlf)+ space(2) + Parameters!time.Label
```

However, when I run the report the times are not lined up properly. How can I get them to line up?

> Tuesday    9:00 AM
>
> Wednesday     9:00 AM
>
> Thursday    9:00 AM
>
> Friday   9:00 AM

Comment: Do you want to vary the space between the day and the time or do you just want to right justify these so the entire value is aligned by the time?

Comment: I would like the times to be aligned.

Comment: I understand: if you set the cell to be right justified, the times will be aligned, but the days no longer will be left justified. Is that adequate? Or do you need both day and time left aligned?

Comment: I need them both to be left aligned.

Answer (score 0):

If you can sacrifice the day's left alignment, then set the entire cell to be right aligned.

If you need both to be aligned, then:

The easiest method would be to separate the values into two text boxes or cells. Set both to grow automatically, and then make sure you have the same number of lines in each.

Otherwise you will need to use a fixed width font so you can add padding manually.

Add a function to the report's embedded code (Report menu -> Report Properties -> Code pane) such as:

```
Public Function ShowParameterValues(ByVal parameter as Parameter, ByVal timeStr As String) as String
   Dim s as String = ""
   If parameter.IsMultiValue then
      For i as integer = 0 to parameter.Count-1
         s = s & CStr(parameter.Value(i)).PadRight(15, " ")
         s = s & timeStr & vbcrlf

      Next
   Else
      s = CStr(parameter.Value)
   End If
   Return s
End Function
```

Call this from your textbox with

```
=Code.ShowParameterValues(Parameters!DelDay , Parameters!time.Label)
```

Comment: I ended up just right justifying the cell. The user isn't concerned about the day of the week being right justified as well. If you put this down as an answer, I will flag it. Thanks for your help.